# The complementary of an open ball is connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$, show that $\mathbb R^2-A$ is connected.

I was assuming that  $\mathbb R^2-A$ is disconnected, so that it has a separation. However, unlike how we prove $\mathbb R$ is connected (in which we assume $\mathbb R$ is disconnected and finding a point in $\mathbb R$ that does not belong to any part of the separation), I could not find such a point for $\mathbb R^2-A$. Can anyone give me some hint? Very much thanks!

Comment: [Prove it is even path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1275345).